# No mapping for POST /imports

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

Please help if you have any idea why its not working. I have been trying to test it with Postman for hours but no luck.

ImportController:

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/imports")
@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 20971520) //20MB
public class ImportController {
    @Autowired
    private ImportRepository importRepository;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("ImportController initialized.");
    }


    // Create a new import
    @PostMapping
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public ImportModel createImport(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        // Save the file to the server's file system
        Path filePath = Paths.get("", file.getOriginalFilename());
        file.transferTo(filePath);

        // Create an ImportModel object with the file path and save it to the database
        ImportModel importModel = new ImportModel();
        importModel.setFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());
        importModel.setFilePath(filePath.toString());
        return importRepository.save(importModel);
    }
```

This is the Controller that has the request and supposed to have the mappings

Comment: What is the full url you're using and what is the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is expecting "/imports/".

On the class:

```
@RequestMapping("/imports")
```

and then again on the method:

```
@PostMapping
@RequestMapping(value = "/", . . . .
```

Forget the 2nd `@RequestMapping` and just use

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data")
```

There is really no need to mix it all up and do double definitions.